# Change app name in pubspec.yaml cause error on imports

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a new flutter project in AS and for some reason the name in pubspec.yaml for my app is just app even when I named it something else when I created new app

```
name: app
description: My new application.
```

When I rename it to whatever I need then all my imports error out in my project.

Example:

```
import 'package:app/main.dart';
```

So how do you change the name in pubspec.yaml without crashing all imports

UPDATE
After renaming name, AS doesn't show package option with the new name

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you need to change the imported packages which now has a different source. The usual form for importing packages is like this:

`import 'package:ApplicationNameDefinedInPubspec/FolderInLib/SubFolder/DartFileName.dart';`.

so for example in your case it should be something like this:

`import 'package:NewAppName/main.dart';`.

And also to change the app name showing on the devices, the Flutter documentation points out where you can change the display name of your application for both Android and IOS. This may be what you are looking for:

- [Preparing an Android App for Release](https://flutter.io/android-release/)
- [Preparing an iOS App for Release](https://flutter.io/ios-release/)

**For Android**

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` as the `application` entry.

> Review the default **App Manifest** file **AndroidManifest.xml** located in
>   **/android/app/src/main/** and verify the values are correct,
>   especially:
>
> **application**: Edit the **application** tag to reflect the final name of the
>   app.

**For iOS**

See the `Review Xcode project settings` section:

> Navigate to your target’s settings in Xcode:
>
> In Xcode, open **Runner.xcworkspace** in your app’s **ios** folder.
>
> To view your app’s settings, select the **Runner** project in the Xcode project
>   navigator. Then, in the main view sidebar, select the **Runner** target.
>
> Select the **General** tab. Next, you’ll verify the most important
>   settings:
>
> **Display Name**: the name of the app to be displayed on the home screen
>   and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Taba. Please see updated question. Problem is that AS doesn't show the option with updated name. I don't care about the app name in IOS or Android for now.. I just want to rename it in pubspec.yaml

Comment: what is the new name in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: so replace this: `import 'package:app/main.dart';` with this: `import 'package:test/main.dart';`.

Comment: I understand that... but once again I don't want to do it manually.. I want that to be done by selecting it from the option window. But option window show old package name

Answer (score 6):

For example, if the default app name is

```
name: defaultappname
description: My new application.
```

and you want to change it to

```
name: app
description: My new application.
```

then you have to just do the search and replace operation:

[image: Search and Replace Operation]